# Recovering a disabled Intellij intention setting

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA, when editing Java code, by default shows an intention for converting a switch statement from the old style to the new style. I disabled this, and now have changed my mind and want to use it after all. How do you recover a disabled intention setting?

I've tried looking at the 'edit intention settings' dialog, that can be accessed with Ctrl-Alt-S, that just shows a long list of intention settings that are all enabled. No sign of the one to convert switch statement from old to new style. Does that only show the ones that are currently enabled? Or should it be showing the switch statement one, somewhere that I am not seeing it? It seems to be showing the other ones regarding switch statements, under Control Flow. Should I be looking somewhere else, or doing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an **Inspection**, not an Intention Action, you can either reset the inspections profile to default or enable this specific inspection:

[image: inspection]